# Power Automate Desktop "Unknown Action"

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, rpa, power-platform

I was trying this new RPA of microsoft, Power Automate Desktop and building some desktop flows, they all worked correctly, in my fifth flow I was half the process when the flow started giving me errors on the first action (I had tested it like 15 times before), so I decided to close the editor and give it a try one more time, that's where I se the "Uknown Action", almost all my actions were replaced by this as shown on the image below.

[Unkown action with error panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhIg9.png)

I closed it and as I checked all my other flows (already tested), they all had most of their actions changed by this. Also I noticed my modules or categories were reduced to 5, the web automation, OCR, almost every module is now not available.

Why did this happened? is a licence problem or a limit of executions problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the "Unknown action, Module [...] or action[...] not found" by instaling the latest version of Power Automate desktop (March 2021 or newer).

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me when my free trial expired. I bought a license and reinstalled and it fixed it for me. Using power automate desktop with office 365 E3.